# scraping historical shareprices using Rvest is not working

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I m trying to extract historical share price information from a web-page. However, rvest throws xml error.

I'm a newbie to this and could someone help me understand how to make this work?

**Here is my R script using rvest**

```
share_url <- "https://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/hist_stock_result.php?ex=B&sc_id=ITC&mycomp=ITC"
share.data<- read_html(share_url)
share_css<-"#mc_mainWrapper > div.PA10 > div.FL > div.PT15 > div.MT12 > table > tbody"

share_table<- share.data %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes("table") %>% html_table()
```

**Error:**

> Error in UseMethod("read_xml") :    no applicable method for
> 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "c('xml_document',
> 'xml_node')"

Comment: You call read_html again on the wrong object type. Change to  `share.data %>% html_nodes("table") %>% html_table()`

Comment: Thanks @QHarr - tried your suggestion - but got this error                                                 Error in matrix(unlist(values), ncol = width, byrow = TRUE) : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL

Comment: then your css selector didn't match anything in the returned html doc. It may be either the wrong css selector or the target element is js rendered and thus not present in what you get returned from rvest. You need to inspect the returned html or switch off js temporarily in the browser and check for your target element.

Comment: Currently, I see no data or date range on that page

Comment: https://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/hist_stock_result.php?ex=B&sc_id=ITC&mycomp=ITC - this is the link url  and this is what selector tool returns for the table - .PA10 , tr:nth-child(4) td... I m not well versed with Java or CSS so I m unable to comment on that. Thanks for helping me here Q Harr

Comment: When I go to that link there is no table of shares data. The table is just empty :-( Do you need to select dates?

Comment: Yup I selected a 1 year window - the link i shared has data from 1st Jan'20 to 1st May'21.  If rvest doesnt work are there more elegant ways to do this in R or python?

Comment: Can someone help me here please?

Answer (score 0):

There is the following call when you change the date:

```
POST https://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/hist_stock_result.php
```

The body is form url encoded with the following data (from and to date):

```
frm_dy = "01",
frm_mth = "01",
frm_yr = "2020",
to_dy = "01",
to_mth = "01",
to_yr = "2021",
hdn = "daily"
```

The following code use `httr` and `rvest` to get the table data:

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)

resp <- POST(
    "https://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/hist_stock_result.php",
    query = list(
        ex = "B",
        sc_id = "ITC",
        mycomp = "ITC"
    ),
    body = list(
        frm_dy = "01",
        frm_mth = "01",
        frm_yr = "2020",
        to_dy = "01",
        to_mth = "01",
        to_yr = "2021",
        hdn = "daily"
    ), 
    encode = "form")

table <- html_table(content(resp),fill=TRUE)[[3]]

print(table)
```

[kaggle link](https://www.kaggle.com/bertrandmartel/moneycontrolhistoricaldata)